# Search function not working for question mark

Tags: javascript

Here if I try to search with full sentence Search function is not working.
Please let me know what is the solution if I need to search with the strings separated by "?"

```js
function myFunction() {
  var str = "How are You? I'm good";
  var n = str.search("How are You? I'm good");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: `search` converts your argument to regex, and `?` has special meaning in regex

Comment: You pass regex to search, so the questionmark has to be escaped.

    var str = "How are You? I'm good";
    var regex = /[\?]/g;
    str.search(regex);

Comment: Use `indexOf` instead: `str.indexOf("How are You?")`. If you just want to check if it has a substring, use [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

Answer (score 1):

Use str.indexOf('How are You? I'm good') if you do not want to use the power of regex. It is faster too.

Comment: The question was closed 7 minutes ago and this is already mentioned in the duplicates.